# How to not create a race condition when cancelling a long running library function

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

`someLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction` is a library function that I can't change, the library has another function, `cancelSomeLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction` that makes the first function abort early that's designed to be called from another thread. The problem I'm having is it's possible that the the coroutine started from `run()` may not be in the `someLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction` yet when I call `cancel()`, thus the second long running function won't be cancelled. Even if I added a flag that checks in between the two functions in the coroutine, there'd still be a race condition. What is a proper way of doing this?

```
fun cancel() {
    cancelSomeLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction()
}

fun run() {
    launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        someLongRunningFunction()
        //We could check flag here but it's still a race condition
        someLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The coroutine way would be to use a Mutex. This is assuming that

1. `someLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction()` returns immediately, and it's its asynchronous work that you're cancelling with the cancel function.
2. `cancelSomeLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction()` doesn't return until the work is actually canceled, i.e. the library itself is thread-safe, so it's not possible to start the long running function in between calling the cancel function and the cancel function returning. Your example abstracts that away since we're not calling these library functions on an instance of anything.

```
private var isLibraryFunctionCallCancelled = false
private val someLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunctionMutex = Mutex()

fun cancel() {
    launch {
        someLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunctionMutex.withLock {
            cancelSomeLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction()
            isLibraryFunctionCallCancelled = true
        }
    }
}

fun run() {
    launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        someLongRunningFunction()
        someLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunctionMutex.withLock {
            if(!isLibraryFunctionCallCancelled )
                someLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `someLongRunningCancellableLibraryFunction()` doesn't return immediately, it's a long running function that the cancel function can abort early

Comment: So it blocks until its work is finished, but will return early if the other function is called from some other thread?

Comment: Yes correct. About #2 I will check that now, but I doubt it's true.

Comment: Checked #2, that's not true either. cancel function returns immediately, and the long running function could take a second or two to stop blocking after that